# How to disable AutoCommit in Postgresql ODBC

Tags: postgresql, psqlodbc

I'm trying to connect oracle to postgreSQL via db link. Is there any option to disable AutoCommit in Postgresql ODBC?

odbc.ini looks like

```
[PG]
Description = PG
Driver = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
ServerName = xxxxx
Username = authenticator
Password = xxxx
Port = 5432
Database = master

[Default]
Driver = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
```

I tried autocommit=false and autocommit=off but it did not work.

Comment: Try setting it via API call, refer [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/56ABD9CF.7030400%40aklaver.com), may be old, but worth a try

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What I understood that I should apply this function SQLSetConnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, 0), but I do not know where to set it in Linux. Does anyone have an idea?